# How to get element in JSON string

Tags: c#, json

I have this JSON string called assignee:

```
{
    "id": 15247055788906,
    "gid": "15247055788906",
    "name": "Bo Sundahl",
    "resource_type": "user"
}
```

I want to get the "name" element and its value if it's not null. I have tried

```
var jobject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JObject>(assignee);
```

And

```
var jo = JObject.Parse(assignee);
```

I tried looping through it but I just get null exception or empty output even though if I just print the assignee variable itself its filled with data.

My loop is like:

```
foreach (var result in jobject["name"])
{
    Debug.WriteLine(result);
}
```

Comment: Parse it to a proper C# class instead of `JObject`, it makes all this complication go away.

Comment: its really not necessary for such small data, string name = jobject["name"]; was enough

Comment: There are many benefits though. Compile time type checking is the obvious one. However there are less tangible ones, for example the readability of the code.

Comment: @fasola it's not about the verbosity of the method, it's about the correct way to handle it. That's why I deleted my answer and upvoted david's

Comment: Another point to note is that deserialising to a concrete class is almost twice as fast as using `JObject`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get name use this

```
string name = jobject["name"];
```

Answer (score 3):

The simplest and best way is to deserialise to a C# class, for example:

```
public class Data
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    //etc..
}
```

And deserialise like this

```
var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Data>(json);
var name = data.Name;
```

Comment: Upvoted...but, if the incoming data is "dirty" and you don't know all the forms, this approach can be problematic.

Comment: @Clay OP specifically needs the `Name` property, so that's not a concern here.

Comment: Agreed - just making a minor point. I do agree that this is the best approach...for both maintainability and performance reasons. I've experienced dirty data on larger json strings w/o knowing the source. Very unsatisfactory :-(

Comment: One work around for not knowing if a property exists or not is have a wrapper json package with meta data `{ "type" : "myType1", "Payload" : "{ inner json payload}" }` This of course assumes you control the caller

Answer (score 0):

Using `["name"]` returns a `JToken`, it is null if the property doesn't exist

```cs
JToken token = jo["name"];
Debug.WriteLine(token?.ToString() ?? "<default value>");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know properties beforehand, you can loop through JObject properties and get name value pairs as following:

```
var jsonObject = JObject.Parse(str);
foreach (var item in jsonObject)
{
   var name = item.Key;
   JToken token = item.Value;
   if (token is JValue)
   {
      var value = token.Value<string>();
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how it should work:

```
class Data
  {
    public long? Id { get; set; }
    public string Gid { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Resource_Type { get; set; }
  }
  class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

      string assignee = "{\"id\": 15247055788906, \"gid\": \"15247055788906\", \"name\": \"Bo Sundahl\", \"resource_type\": \"user\"}";
      Data data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Data>(assignee);
      Console.WriteLine(data.Id);
      Console.WriteLine(data.Gid);
      Console.WriteLine(data.Name);
      Console.WriteLine(data.Resource_Type);
      Console.ReadLine();
    }
  }
```